# Name of Rubik's Cube position with swapped corners & centers

Tags: rubiks-cube, twisty-puzzles

What is this Rubik's Cube setup called? I tried to swap the corners and centers of each side. Is there a name for this?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the [superflip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superflip), the position of a 3x3x3 cube where all edge pieces have been flipped in place, but applied to a 5x5x5 cube using only its outer layers. My preferred method for doing this is the following:

[image]
(Shown for a 3x3x3 cube, on a 5x5x5 treat the inner layers as if they form a single middle layer)

Comment: Oh.. So it is well known configuration. Though, I made it from scratch and done without solving cube first.

Comment: Also the superflip is one position that requires the maximum number of turns (in half-turn metric to solve), 20.

Comment: I believe not required to solve the metric first. That's how I made it up

Answer (score 0):

Image and sequence to produce superflip from https://ruwix.com/the-rubiks-cube/rubiks-cube-patterns-algorithms/